# Structures: Undeclared identifiers

Tags: c, struct, undeclared-identifier

I'm trying to use structures in my program and I'm getting a bunch of error messages saying that time1, time2, and hourDif are undeclared identifiers. I thought I declared these structures the way you are supposed to, so I am confused as to what the problem is.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time1 {
    int seconds1;
    int minutes1;
    int hours1;
};

struct time2 {
    int seconds2;
    int minutes2;
    int hours2;
};

    int timeDif(time1, time2) {
        struct dif {
            int secDif = time2.seconds2 - time1.seconds1;
            int minDif = time2.minutes2 - time1.minutes1;
            int hourDif = time2.hours2 - time1.hours1;
        };

        printf("The difference is %d:%d:%d\n", hourDif, minDif, secDif);
    }



    int main(void) {

        printf("Enter seconds1 (ss)\n");
        scanf("%d", &time1.seconds1);

        printf("Enter minutes1 (mm)\n");
        scanf("%d", &time1.minutes1);

        printf("Enter hours1 (hh)\n");
        scanf("%d", &time1.hours1);

        printf("Enter seconds2 (ss)\n");
        scanf("%d", &time2.seconds2);

        printf("Enter minutes2 (mm)\n");
        scanf("%d", &time2.minutes2);

        printf("Enter hours2 (hh)\n");
        scanf("%d", &time2.hours2);

        timeDif(time1, time2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really seem to be stuck in the very basics.  Please get yourself a read in some book or online resources about C. This would be much more productive for yourself at this stage of your experience than using an Q&A site like SO.

Answer (score 1):

You need not define three structs, because they are the same type — time. You can only define only one struct `time`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time {
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
    int hours;
};

void timeDif(struct time time1,struct time time2) {
    struct time diff= {
         time2.seconds - time1.seconds,
         time2.minutes - time1.minutes,
         time2.hours - time1.hours
    };

    printf("The difference is %d:%d:%d\n", diff.hours, diff.minutes, diff.seconds);
}

int main(void) {
    struct time time1,time2,diff;
    printf("Enter seconds1 (ss)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time1.seconds);

    printf("Enter minutes1 (mm)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time1.minutes);

    printf("Enter hours1 (hh)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time1.hours);

    printf("Enter seconds2 (ss)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time2.seconds);

    printf("Enter minutes2 (mm)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time2.minutes);

    printf("Enter hours2 (hh)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time2.hours);

    timeDif(time1, time2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function definition

```
int timeDif(time1, time2) {
    struct dif {
        int secDif = time2.seconds2 - time1.seconds1;
        int minDif = time2.minutes2 - time1.minutes1;
        int hourDif = time2.hours2 - time1.hours1;
    };

    printf("The difference is %d:%d:%d\n", hourDif, minDif, secDif);
}
```

the compiler consideres identifiers time1 and time2 as names of objects. But they are not defined because you did not specify their type. I think that you forgot to specify the name of the objects and specified only their types. The function declaration could look like

```
int timeDif(struct time1 t1, struct time2 t2);
```

Take into account that you have to use structure tags with structure names in declarations of objects of a structure type.

Also the function returns nothing though it has return type int. It does not make sense. And you may not initialize data members of a structure within its definition in C.

Thus this structure definition

```
    struct dif {
        int secDif = time2.seconds2 - time1.seconds1;
        int minDif = time2.minutes2 - time1.minutes1;
        int hourDif = time2.hours2 - time1.hours1;
    };
```

is invalid.

The same problem exists with function call

```
timeDif(time1, time2);
```

I think you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time 
{
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
    int hours;
};


struct time_dif 
{
    int secDif;
    int minDif;
    int hourDif;
};

struct time_dif timeDif( struct time t1, struct time t2 ) 
{
    struct time_dif dif = 
    { 
        t2.seconds - t1.seconds,
        t2.minutes - t1.minutes,
        t2.hours   - t1.hours
    };

    return dif;
}



int main(void) 
{
    struct time t1, t2;

    printf( "Enter hours1 (hh): " );
    scanf( "%d", &t1.hours );

    printf( "Enter minutes1 (mm): " );
    scanf( "%d", &t1.minutes );

    printf( "Enter seconds1 (ss): " );
    scanf( "%d", &t1.seconds );

    printf( "Enter hours2 (hh): " );
    scanf( "%d", &t2.hours );

    printf( "Enter minutes2 (mm): " );
    scanf( "%d", &t2.minutes );

    printf( "Enter seconds2 (ss): " );
    scanf( "%d", &t2.seconds );


    struct time_dif dif = timeDif( t1, t2 );

    printf( "The difference is %d:%d:%d\n", dif.hourDif, dif.minDif, dif.secDif );

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that difference for example of minutes can be a negative value. You should rewrite function `timeDid` such a way that it would provide the correct difference of two times.

Comment: Under C90 rules, `int timeDif(time1, time2)` declares a function that takes two integer arguments called `time1` and `time2` — implicit `int`.  They're no relation to the `struct time1` or `struct time2`.  The three structure type definitions is also OTT.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Taking into account the error message the compiler does not uses old rules of C90 that now are considered like errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of errors in your code. I made some modifications in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time1 {
    int seconds1;
    int minutes1;
    int hours1;
};

struct time2 {
    int seconds2;
    int minutes2;
    int hours2;
 };

int timeDif(struct time1 time1, struct time2 time2) { 
    int secDif = time2.seconds2 - time1.seconds1;
    int minDif = time2.minutes2 - time1.minutes1;
    int hourDif = time2.hours2 - time1.hours1;

    printf("The difference is %d:%d:%d\n", hourDif, minDif, secDif);
}

int main(void) {
    //declare the variable to use.
    struct time1 time1;
    struct time2 time2;
    printf("Enter seconds1 (ss)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time1.seconds1);

    printf("Enter minutes1 (mm)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time1.minutes1);

    printf("Enter hours1 (hh)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time1.hours1);

    printf("Enter seconds2 (ss)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time2.seconds2);

    printf("Enter minutes2 (mm)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time2.minutes2);

    printf("Enter hours2 (hh)\n");
    scanf("%d", &time2.hours2);

    timeDif(time1, time2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are referring to any `struct` or `class`, you have to create `objects`. You cannot use them directly, like `scanf("%d", &time1.seconds1);`. Instead, create an object of `time1` first, then use that object. It is really simple :

```
struct time1 t1;    // creates an object t1 of the type time1.
scanf("%d",&t1.seconds1);
```

The main reason is : when you define a `struct`, you are actually defining a `type` , just like an `int` or a `char` data type. You never directly use them like `scanf("%d",&int);`. You always create a variable of type `int`, and then use it further. Similarly, you create `objects` for struct, and then use them further.

Also, there are few problems with the function `timeDif`, such as it not returning any value. Since it doesn't seem like your function needs to return anything once it has already pritned the result, declare it as `void`. Also, there is no reason for you to have the `struct` inside this function, since you are printing the result in the same function, and haven't used the struct anywhere, and this struct is error-prone too.

Here is the modified version of your code: http://ideone.com/uzBnVS